# Yes, I'm dumb - I drilled into wall backing my electrical panel

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, drill, subpanel

so... I was drilling into a wall and the drill was having a hard time. I figured I just needed to keep going and I did and it finally went through. Afterwards I realized my electrical panel was directly behind that wall and then noticed metal shavings around. What are the chances I have a huge problem??!!!

Comment: If you can post a picture of the hole/surrounding area, that would help.

Comment: You have survived the most dangerous part!

Comment: Are you sure it penetrated the panel? Can you look inside the panel and check?

Comment: We know you missed the buss bars because you only had shavings, buss bar contact would equal big boom and your drill bit would not be any good. But will need to check for cut insulation.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to answer since we don't know if it caused any mechanical or electrical damage, also is the hole in an area where it could be seen and repaired. I am assuming the answer is no since you didn't say you could see the hole. You simply state there are metal savings. You might want to bring in a trained professional who could safely remove certain parts and investigate the damage. Think of it as "I might have drilled a hole in my brake line, what do I do now."

Stay safe and good luck.